# Why does a network adapter without any address still receive IP traffic?

Tags: linux, networking

**Question**

A nix box with a network adapter in the UP state, but without any address, still receives IP network packet data. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long is has a cable connected and it is in the UP state, it listens passively to it. We often in the network field use that functionality to listen in a secondary interface for the traffic of a particular segment of the network.

That does not means however the traffic is passed to the upper layers of the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Even though IPTables is fully locked down? ('DROP' _everything_)

Comment: Not to mention broadcasts (ARP requests) that the local network sends out.

Comment: ARP traffic we know and understand, and expect, same with broadcast. But this is actual IP traffic.

Comment: IPTables doesn't prevent the traffic from being received; it just prevents the traffic from reaching the application (or from being processed by the kernel).

Comment: Thanks siarcot for the comment. I was confusing it with Cisco hardware. In Cisco routers usually the filtering comes before anything else.

Comment: So how can we fully lock the box while maintaining an UP state for bridging? (We tried EPTables as well).

Comment: You can alway fully lock the box if you know what you are doing. In my opinion a bridge, router, or VPN servers should not offer any more visible services at all. I have a VPN server in Linux, and to enter into ssh, first I have to access the VPN.

Comment: So we have a fully locked box with an adapter in the UP state. Locked by IPTables and EPTables. We are good in your opinion?

Comment: There are no silver bullets. You still have to be in the watch out for flaws in the kernel in whatever functionality you give to the outside world, however the probabilities are far fewer and between with a job well done. For instance, a while ago there were vulnerabilities in tcpdump...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro:  will research this matter further. For now I have marked your response as the correct answer.

Comment: For sure. This is a complex talk, we are just touching the surface. Security is a multi-layer, multi-disciplinar approach, and the sum of all the parts. I also have as policy to not only count on iptables/firewall, but to follow principles as to install the bare minimum, and even then to disable what I do not need.